# For some reason, my loading "circle" will not working when I have it as a method or just normally in an if statement. Anyone know why?

Tags: java, loops, logic-error

Here is the code that I have for my Test program. I have all the code in order to avoid a runtime or syntax error but I don't know if this is a logic error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  static void Load() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r-");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r\\");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r|");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\r/\r");
    Thread.sleep(300);
 }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws InterruptedException {
    // declaring variables
    String user1 = "";
    int password;
    String passyn;
    String account;
    String user2 = "";
    boolean isRunning = true;
    String tryAgain = "";
    int new1Password = 0;
    int new2Password;
    // my code
    while (isRunning) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Load();
      System.out.println("\rWelcome to LOGIN");
      System.out.print("Enter your name(If you don't have an account, type none): ");
      user1 = sc.next();
      if (user1.equals("Dov")) {
        System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
        password = sc.nextInt();
        if (password == 1234) {
          Load();
          System.out.println("\rACCESS GRANTED");
          System.out.printf("Welcome %s", user1);
          isRunning = false;
        } else {
          System.out.print("ACCESS DENIED");
        }
      }
      // end of loop
      else if (user1.equals("None") || user1.equals("none")) {
        System.out.print("Do you have an account: ");
        passyn = sc.nextLine();
        if (passyn.equals("No") || passyn.equals("no")) {
          System.out.print("Type yes to sign up: ");
          account = sc.next();
          if (account.equals("No") || account.equals("No")) {
          } else {
            System.out.print("What is your new username: ");
            user2 = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("What is your password(Numbers only!!): ");
            new1Password = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Would you like to return to the login screen: ");
            tryAgain = sc.next();
            if (tryAgain.equals("no") || tryAgain.equals("No")) {
              isRunning = false;
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (user1.equals(user2)) {
        System.out.print("What is your password: ");
        new2Password = sc.nextInt();
        if (new1Password == new2Password) {
        Load();
        System.out.println("\rACCESS GRANTED");
        System.out.printf("Welcome %s", user1);
        isRunning = false;
        } else {
          System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
        }
      } else {
        isRunning = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works as a loop continuously running until ACCESS GRANTED. The program works fine but my loading system never works. I was running in it in a different program, also as a method and it worked fine. I insert it into the Test.java program and nothing happens. Any thoughts? (I am using replit.com for my IDE)

Comment: what does "my loading system never works" mean?

Comment: the code works fine in idea, and i saw |\/- rotating , and it prints`Welcome to LOGIN
Enter your name(If you don't have an account, type none): Dov
Enter your password: 1234
ACCESS GRANTED
Welcome Dov`

Answer (score 0):

The code worked fine for me too, as user9594794 mentioned in the comments.

The only suggestions I have are:

1. Refactor your loading method:

   ```
    char[] sequence = {'-', '\\', '|', '/', '-', '\\', '|', '/'};
    int n = 3; // or however many times you want the spinning text
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (char c : sequence) {
            System.out.print("\r" + c);
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Take a good look at your loop and conditions and possibly refactor those as well. The comment "end of loop" doesn't correspond with the actual end of the loop. It is true that the loop *may* not have any more iterations after that point (user Dov and password 1234) but this may not be the case.